# Angular2 off-side anytime crash debug

Tags: angular

I am developing an Android2 app. Since this app will be used by many people I want to be able to debug problems without having access to the user's computer.

For example the app crashes or hangs on one of my users - I want to get notified that such a thing has happened and be able to see the state of the program at the moment of the crash or at least the stacktrace so that I can fix the problem.

How to achieve this ?

P.S. I am looking for something like Crashlitycs for mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has [this feature](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html) out of box. What you can do is create an api at the backend and call it to register errors. Angular side would be like this:

```
class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor() { 
   super();
  }

  handleError(error) {
    // send the error to the backend here
    super.handleError(error)
  }

}
```

And in the module:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}]
})
class MyModule {}
```

Comment: Right. I have seen this however I am looking for something that can show me the state of the app at the moment of the crash. Currently I develop locally and print almost everything to the console so when something goes wrong I have the full state of the app from the beginning.